# debian 10 bonding error boot bond0

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

I try to set up bonding on my debian 10 computer. I have 2 NIC card, I try to use enp1s0fX port. Sample of my `interfaces` file

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
   address 192.168.211.124
   gateway 192.168.211.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.211.0
   bond-slaves enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1 enp1s0f2
   bond-mode active-backup
   bond-miimon 100
```

When I reboot I got this message in `dmesg` :
`bond0: option mode: unable to set because the bond device has slaves`

I don't understand why

Comment: Did you have a look here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifenslave/+bug/1280366

Comment: The order of interface declarations (perhaps related to the bugs link in above comment?) does matter. From [some tests done before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543275/251756), declaring enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1 enp1s0f2 after bond0 rather than before helps prevent problems.

Comment: I tired to declare bond0 in the begining of interfaces files, but nothing change I've already same problem

Answer (score 0):

This message comes from the kernel, not from ifup:

```
bond0: option mode: unable to set because the bond device has slaves
```

You can't change bonding mode after you have interfaces associated to the bond.

Since active-backup is the default mode (and I assume that is the mode of your choice),  you can simply remove `bond-mode` from the interface configuration.

If you really need to set the bonding mode, use a similar pattern:

```
auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0
    bond-mode active-backup

auto enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary enp1s0f0
    bond-mode active-backup

auto enp1s0f2
iface enp1s0f2 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary enp1s0f0
    bond-mode active-backup

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-slaves none
    bond-primary enp1s0f0
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 100
```